# Paypal API: This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have set up a sandbox environment and enabled Business Pro so that they can accept Credit Card payments.

I am using the DirectPayment function in PHP that you provide on website and pass the following parameters: $paymentType, $paymentAmount, $creditCardType, $creditCardNumber,$expDate, $cvv2, $firstName, $lastName, $street, $city, $state, $zip, $countryCode, $currencyCode

It makes the call with $resArray=hash_call("DoDirectPayment", $nvpstr);

and the $nvpstr string is '&AMT=1&CURRENCYCODE=GBP&PAYMENTACTION=Sale&CREDITCARDTYPE=Visa&ACCT=4137350247384347&EXPDATE=122020&CVV2=123&FIRSTNAME=Test&LASTNAME=Last&STREET=TheLarchlands&CITY=Penn&STATE=Buckinghamshire&COUNTRYCODE=GB&IPADDRESS=90.207.76.28'

Why am I getting a failure response:

Direct credit card payment API call failed. 
Detailed Error Message: This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration.
Short Error Message: Invalid Configuration
Error Code: 10501
Error Severity Code: Error

Thanks!

Comment: Fix the merchant config in your PayPal sandbox

Comment: My account type in sandbox is already set to 'Account Type:
Business-Pro', I am using the API Credentials provided there and the debt card information I am using is also from one the sandbox accounts I created.

Comment: do you have the debug ID?

Answer (score 1):

Invalid Merchant Configuration means that DoDirectPayment is not enabled on your account, or you have not yet accepted the billing agreement for the $30/mo that PayPal charges you for it.

What could be going on, though, is that you have been approved and agreed to the billing, but you're setup on a different version of Payments Pro that requires you to use the PayFlow API instead of DoDirectPayment.  Payments Pro 3.0 would give you access to DoDirectPayment only.  Payments Pro 1.5 would give you access to PayFlow only.  Payments Pro 2.0 should give you access to both of those APIs so you could use either one you want (although, I have seen where 2.0 accounts still require PayFlow for some reason.)

I actually have a blog article on the [History of PayPal Payments Pro](https://www.angelleye.com/paypal-payments-pro-dodirectpayment-vs-payflow/) if you care to read more details about that.

If it turns out you do need PayFlow, take a look at this [PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/).  It has a PayFlow credit card call setup as a sample and an template for you (as well as the same for pretty much every other PayPal Classic API call they offer) so you can have it done within minutes.

Comment: Thanks very much for the in depth reply Andrew. Il will have a look into this later on today and let you know how I get on. Im new here, am I correct in saying that I press the tick button for the answer which answered my question?